# Removing password plain text from JMX file

Tags: jmeter, jmx, spring-jms, jmeter-plugins

There is a project I am working on that uses the jmx file to run some performance tests on an API with JMeter.
API needs authentication and the username and password is plain text on the JMX file using "password123".
I need to remove this plain text password so when code gets pushed to gitlab, doesn't go with the password as well.
Any help would be really appreciated.
This is how the section of the file looks like that has the username/password:

```
<elementProp name="grant_type" elementType="HTTPArgument">
    <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">true</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="Argument.value">password</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
    <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="Argument.name">grant_type</stringProp>
</elementProp>
<elementProp name="username" elementType="HTTPArgument">
    <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">true</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="Argument.value">johnSmith</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
    <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="Argument.name">username</stringProp>
</elementProp>
<elementProp name="password" elementType="HTTPArgument">
    <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">true</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="Argument.value">password123</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
    <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="Argument.name">password</stringProp>
</elementProp>
```

Comment: Can you pass it by env variable? `${__groovy(System.getenv('JM_PWD'),)}`

Comment: @lojza can you show me a sample code how would that look like? I am new in Java and jMetter world. Thank you

Comment: Set env variable in shel `JM_PWD=password123` or in docker by `docker run -e JM_PWD=password123` and then run jmeter with jmx where `<stringProp name="Argument.value">${__groovy(System.getenv('JM_PWD'),)}</stringProp>`

Answer (score 2):

Including sensitive information (e.g. password) in the JMX is not advisable. You can pass the values when the tests are executed

There are a number of options available to pass the runtime value to the test scripts

1. Passing the value as a JMeter property from the command line

```
jmeter.sh -n -t test-plan.jmx -Jpassword=Abcd1234
```

2. Set the password in the user.properties

```
password=Abcd1234
```

You need to change the JMX file

```
<stringProp name="Argument.value">password123</stringProp>
```

with

```
<stringProp name="Argument.value">${__P(password,)}</stringProp>
```

3. You can set the password as an env variable and retrieve it with

```
${__env(password,,)}
```

4. You can pass the variable when the test is started with the [BeanShell server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) configuration.

Comment: 2 & 3 sound what I need. 
Can you please show me how I can set password to user.properties and as an env (so I can try both methods).
I added the password to "User defined variables" on JMeter UI but what it did is that it just generated this code:

          <elementProp name="testPassword" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">testPassword</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">somePassword</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
which is still plain text password

Comment: 1. The `user.properties` file is located in JMTER_HOME/bin folder. Open the file in a text editor and add `password=Abcd1234` to the bottom of the file. Save the file and restart the JMeter,

Comment: 2. TO SET ENV VAR :: You can run `export password=Abcd1234` or `set password=Adbcd1234` (windows)  from the command window where you start the  JMeter

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to save the password in the .jmx file you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read it from JMeter Property, to wit change your `password123` to `${__P(password,)}`

Once done you will be able to pass the actual password value during JMeter test execution via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

```
jmeter -Jpassword=password123 -n -t test.jmx ....
```

and __P() function will substitute its placeholder with the value passed via `-J` command-line argument.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)